# Geometric analogy subdifferential

Tags: convex-analysis

Hy guys,

Is there a geometric analogy that could help me to understand the concept of subdifferential, i mean how can i geometrically visualize the definition at least for simple cases?

Answer (score 2):

Look at Figures 1, 2, and 3 of this [paper](https://see.stanford.edu/materials/lsocoee364b/01-subgradients_notes.pdf).